# Browser CORS error while implementing OKTA SAML in localhost

Tags: javascript, express, cors, xmlhttprequest, okta

Using OKTA SAML, I'm putting in place an authentication system. According to my process, the UI will access the API with or without a JWT token, and the API will check to see whether the JWT token is present in the header; if it is not, the API will reroute the request to an endpoint that is pointing to an OKTA SAML configuration, where the user will be prompted to log in.
In the same way, if the JWT token validation fails, it will reroute to the OKTA SAML configuration and prompt the user to log in.

```
UI server : http://localhost:8080
API server endpoint: http://localhost:8085/api/v2/manage-course/course/poc 
OKTA entrypoint: https://org.oktapreview.com/app/org_saml20app_1/exkphv74h91FTg2Iasddasdyq/sso/saml
```

While doing that, I am getting a **CORS** error from the browser. Can anybody please help me resolve the **CORS** error?
[image]

**CORS Headers:**

```
const corsOptions = {
            "origin": ['http://localhost:8080', 'https://org.oktapreview.com'],
            "methods": "GET,HEAD,PUT,PATCH,POST,DELETE",
            "preflightContinue": false,
            "optionsSuccessStatus": 200
        }
        app.use(cors(corsOptions));
```

Comment: Yes, I did this.
```app.use("/", function (req, res, next) {
            res.set({
                'Strict-Transport-Security': 'max-age=31536000; includeSubDomains; preload',
                'X-XSS-Protection': '1; mode=block',
                'X-Content-Type-Options': 'nosniff',
                'Access-Control-Allow-Origin': '*',
            });
            next();
        });```

Comment: I have updated in the post. Please let me know if added CORS headers are sufficient.

Comment: 8085 - API server

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/254951/discussion-between-justananothercoder-and-jaromanda-x).